# Return Json Array with bottle

Tags: python, json, bottle

I am trying to return a Json array with Bottle. The code  is:

```
@app.get('/getmyname')
def getmyname():
    ret = """{
            "chart": {
            "type": "column",
            }}""" 
    return json.dumps(ret)
```

However i get some unwanted characters in the resul which looks like this:

```
"{\n\t\t\t\t\"chart\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"column\",\n\t\t\t\t}}"
```

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ret` is *already* a JSON string. There is no need to call `json.dumps` on it.

Either return `ret` directly, or create it as a Python dict and then dump it to JSON:

```
ret = {
        "chart": {
            "type": "column",
         }
      }
return json.dumps(ret)
```